# JavaScript for loop - document.write, cycling through variables

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need some input on the following code. I have the following variables 1 - 11 that I need to cycle through using the document.write function.

var Ref = [ "r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3", ....."r1c11" ];

My for loop first creates unique div ID's. I need help cycling through my variables references for the document.write. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id = 'div' + i;  

c = "rlc"+i

divTag.innerHTML = document.write(c)
document.body.appendChild(divTag);
}
```

Comment: `document.write` returns `undefined`. And better avoid it, see the warning in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29).

Comment: Do you have a suggestion other than document.write? I'm following some other code I found. I'm writing several div's to one table cell.

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to use `document.write()` for here. It seems like you just need to do `divTag.innerHTML = c;` (though I would advise using `divTag.textContent = c;` as a matter of principle unless you specifically want to treat the value `c` as HTML markup.

Comment: An equivalent would be `divTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c));` (but use innerHTML, it's more convenient). And don't forget to declare *c*. ;-)

Comment: Thanks I will use these instead of document.write. Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is pulling all these div's with uniue ID's to a cell. Then choosing which one to show by an if Statement.

Comment: I'm not able to get (divTag.innerHTML = r1c1) to show my data as (document.write (r1c1)) does. I think the reason being is r1 and c1 references the rows and columns and then are combined to shows the cell value in my main table. I'm then attempting to cycle through those values to enter them into a table on the webpage. The following code is where this is derived from.
 'for (var w =  1; w <Row1; w++) 
 for (var z1 =  1; z1 <Col1; z1++) {window["r" + w + "c" + z1]  = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[w].cells[z1 +1].innerHTML;}'

Comment: Here is the code I developed for referencing all the cells in my main table. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1kkb5a66/).